# Bootstrap text align class works only for longer text

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, class

I'm trying to center some text inside a row div. It seems that the bootstrap class `text-center` works only if the text is longer, but it doesn't with one or a few words.

It works with:

```
<div class="row innerpage-dark text-center">
    <h2>Portfolio lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
</div>
```

But it doesn't with:

```
<div class="row innerpage-dark text-center">
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
</div>
```

It seems it works only when the text goes multiline, but not if it's short enough to stay on one line.
Also, the whole div is nested in a `container-fluid` div.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could add `display: inline-block` to the `h2` element: By default its width is 100% (of the parent element), so it actually fills the row horizontally, and the text in it is left-aligned by default.

Alternatively, you could also add `text-align: center` to the `h2`element, or Bootstrap's `text-center` class.

Comment: That's the problem: the class or the inline styling work only when the text exceed the lenght of one line. If I leave everything the same and just put dummy text inside, to make it longer, it starts working. Consider I'm very new to all this, so I'm definitively missing something very easy ^^''

Comment: Extend this `<h2>Portfolio</h2>` to this: `<h2 class="text-center">Portfolio</h2>`